# using REST, how does one set the fan duration for a one-time action?

Tags: duration, nest-api

three fan-related variables are defined in https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api#has_fan

- `has_fan` (r/o, boolean)
- `fan_timer_active` (r/w, boolean)
- `fan_timer_timeout` (r/o, iso8601)

i suspect that `fan_timer_timeout` should be read-write; however, when i PUT

```
    {"fan_timer_active": true, "fan_timer_timeout": "2014-09-30T01:07:29Z"}
```

i get back

```
    No write permission(s) for field(s): fan_timer_timeout
```

none of the examples (on the SDK site) actually change the fan, so no guidance there.

the "non-public API" from "the early days" would have you do this:

```
      fan_timer_duration = seconds
      fan_timer_timeout = time-since-epoch-in-seconds + seconds
```

`fan_timer_timeout` isn't documented on the SDK site; however, doing that yields

```
    No write permission(s) for field(s): fan_timer_duration,fan_timer_timeout
```

could someone clue me in as to what i need to send to get the fan to spin for the next 15 minutes?

many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user configures the fan time duration in the Nest app or on the device, the API only provides a way to trigger a fan event.

It seems that fan time duration is a global setting, and would affect turning on the fan manually at the thermostat, hence why it is read only in the API. (Avoids user confusion)

Comment: thanks very much for the explanation. (i'm don't really agree with the conclusion-about-confusion, but at least i now understand what i'm seeing...) thanks!